# How to interpret the output of the anova command in R?

Tags: r, regression, anova, interpretation

I used the `anova` function in R to get an ANOVA table for my model.

```
fit <- lm(open_time ~ sent_time + email_id + day, data=mydata)
anova(fit)
```

I got the following output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: open_time 
             Df    Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
sent_time    1    222321  222321  2.2673 0.1323
email_id     1     15229   15229  0.1553 0.6936
day          1       798     798  0.0081 0.9281
Residuals 1996 195721653   98057
```

Can someone explain in basic terms as to how can I use this output to get useful information about my model (as in which independent variables are more significant in the prediction model, etc)?